# How to manipulate a local variable in the view and send the data back to the controller in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in Rails, here is what I am trying to do:

A CSV file is read as an Array of hashes and passed to a view as a instance variable. So far this is working fine, the HTML table is fully constructed based on the CSV structure.

Now, I need to edit this HTML table in different ways: "find and replace"  and values in cells, add / remove / rename columns etc

A new CSV will be generated based on the changes that the user has done.

Can I manipulate the array of hashes that contains the table structure and reload the page to recreate the page as the user edits it? It doesn't have to be using ajax, I was thinking of something like passing the values back to the controller and rendering the page again.

The whole editing can be done through text boxes or checkboxes. No need for "real time" interaction with the table.

This the method in the controller that I am using the read the CSV and render the view:

```
  def create
   file = params[:file]
   @logs = CSV.read(file.path, headers:true)
   @headers = @logs.headers
   p @logs
   render 'edit'
 end
```

This is the view:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Edit CSV File</h1>
<%= flash[:notice] %>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tr>
        <% @headers.each do |column| %>
            <th><%= column %></th>
        <% end %>
     </tr>
    <%= p @logs %>
    <% @logs.each do |log| %>
        <tr>
            <% log.each do |key, row| %>
                <td><%= row %></td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to edit the data on your view?

Comment: @Lymuel Yes, I wanna do things like: find and replace operations in the table, add or remove columns etc

Comment: Why not make the view as a form then submit it then update the records.

Comment: @Lymuel Yeah. I am trying to do it now. As I figure that better I will self respond my question